# How to stop onchange Event while i am submiting the form

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am having a javascript function which is calling on onChange Event of textbox
function name is callOnChange()
and my textbox is like

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onChange="callOnChange(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

and also i have a one submit button 
but when i click on the button the onchage event called first and then submit event does not work

so how to deal with it???

i dont want to call "onChange" while i am clicking on submit button

**EDIT**

actually i have just gave example in above question. but i have series of textbox in which i am validating date. Each textbox date must be greater then its above text box then and then below textbox will be enabled otherwise it will remain disabled. so keypress or keydown event will not be very useful here..

Comment: Onchange will trigger if the value within the textbox has changed...
this occurs when you leave the textbox. If you do not want this behaviour try using another event like onKeyDown?

Comment: Please find edited question

Comment: Is the problem really with the onchange event firing?

I think your problem is just that the submit event does not work...

Comment: with asp.net there are plenty of validator controls which would work well for your scenario. this could then all hook up to the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

`onchange` fires when you the element loses focus (and the value changed). This is intended behaviour.

Maybe you want a different event, like `onkeyup`?

Comment: His problem is not the triggered event. It prevents the click event from triggering.

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant way as far as I can tell, but simple way is having delayed event using a global timer, then clicking the submit button will clear that timer.

For this first declare the global variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textbox_changeTimer = 0;
    function callOnChange(sender) {
        //...
    }
<script>
```

Now have such code for the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onchange="textbox_changeTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { callOnChange(this); }, 100);"></asp:TextBox>
```

And finally such submit button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="submit" OnClientClick="window.clearTimeout(textbox_changeTimer);" />
```

This will cancel the onchange event when clicking the button. If you have more than one submit buttons or want bit more elegant code you can hook those events in client side code, iterating over all buttons but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: why javaScript not allowing to trigger two events same time? not asynchronous?

Comment: @SubinJacob not related to synchronous, it's not all events just the specific `onchange` event that indeed cancels form submission as it's usually used for validation.

Comment: The same thing happens to blur event too. Even after cancelling the form submission by preventDefault, the same happens.

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid the change event as Shadow Wizard said. Remember, you would cancel the click event if  you showed `alert("message")` in the change. After, removing the `alert("message")` try `console.log("message")` to see the event. (ctrl+shift+j in chrome to open the javascript console).

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/J5kj2/) jsfiddle (not mine!)